# What are the 9 non-isomorphic rooted trees with 5 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

I'm wondering what the non-isomorphic rooted trees with 5 vertices look like. According to the textbook I'm reading, there are 9 of them but I don't know what they look like or how to draw them or if I'm just misunderstanding the question.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: A rooted tree with 5 vertices isn't that difficult to draw. Have you tried drawing a few of them? How many do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

These are the 9 non-isomorphic rooted trees with 5 vertices.

Answer (score 3):

3 classes of drawings:

- a path on 5 vertices produces 3 rooted trees
- a path on 4 vertices and one additional edge to make 1 vertex of degree 3 yields 4 more
- a vertex of degree 4 surrounded by leaves yields 2 more

Comment: I got them! Thanks for your answer :)